# In how many ways can 7 boys and 3 girls be arranged in a row so that the end positions are taken by the boys?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

In how many ways can 7 different boys and 3 different girls be arranged in a row so that the end positions are taken by the boys and no 2 girls are sat next to each other.

I think I have an idea on how to solve this but my answer differs from the one in the solutions.

First of all choose the boys for the end positions, $7*6$ but since there are 2 end positions we get $7*6*2$. The rest of the boys can be seated in $5!$ ways.

Now consider the configuration $$BXBXBXBXBXBXB$$

Where $X$ is a potential position for a girl to sit. There are 6 such positions so for the girls its $\tbinom 63$

Putting it all together gives $$\tbinom 63 *5! *5 *4 *2$$

But the answer in the solutions is $3!*\tbinom 63$

Comment: Where do you get $5^*4$?  There are $7$ boys who might be in slot #1, then $6$ who might take up slot #10, hence $7^*6$ ways to populate the ends.

Comment: @lulu, Youre right,I dont know why I did that. But the answer is still wrong according to the solutions

Comment: There is no reason to multiply the number of ways to select the end positions by $2$.  There are $7$ ways to fill the left end, which leaves you with $6$ ways to fill the right end.  The answer in the solution manual is the number of ways of arranging the three girls in the six available spots.

Comment: I expect the problem said that the boys were identical.  Otherwise the answer is missing a $7!$ term

Answer (score 5):

You need to count ways to :

- Line up the seven boys in a row.
- Line up the three girls in a row.
- Select three of the six spaces between the boys to merge the lines.

The full answer is:

$$7!\,3!\,\binom{6}{3}$$