# How Many Ways to Arrange These Boys and Girls?

Tags: combinatorics

> There are $7$ boys and $3$ girls.  In how many ways can they be arranged in a row such that the two ends are occupied by boys and no two girls are seated together?

The answer is  $6 \cdot 5 \cdot 4 \cdot 7!$ and the book gave the same explanation is the same as the one [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1498329/in-how-many-ways-can-7-boys-and-3-girls-be-arranged-in-a-row-so-that-the-end-pos).  This was my analysis.  Can you explain why it's wrong?

There are $7 \cdot 6$ ways to fill the first and the last slot.  If we ignore the rules for a moment, there are $8!$ ways to fill the remaining slots.

1. Any time we have two girls together is unacceptable.  So, we can count the two girls as one person.  This gives us $7!$ unacceptable arrangements before considering the different choices in the two-girl spot.
2. Since there are $3 \cdot 2$ ways to fill the two-girl spots, we have $6 \cdot 7!$ unacceptable arrangements in the middle.

It follows that there are $2 \cdot 7!$ acceptable arrangements in the middle, and $7 \cdot 6 \cdot 2 \cdot 7!$ ways to fill the spots according the the rules.  As you see, I am short by $6 \cdot 7!$.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that you counted the time three girls were together two times.

To elaborate, if there are three girls in a row, as in $GGG$, then you exclude these two times when you exlude when two girls are together. This is because you have counted $\color{red}{GG}G$ as well as $G\color{blue}{GG}$. Instead, you should apply the [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) and add the case three girls are together.

Using the inclusion-exclusion principle, we have to add when three girls are in a row in the middle, which is  $5! \times 6$ using your method. This explains why you are short by $6! \times 6 \times 7$ since you have to multiply by $6 \times 7$ later.

Comment: Ok, I see how I double-counted.  TY ....

Comment: @AndyTam What does Double counted mean? I had thought that it was something you used in combinatorial proofs, such as in the IMO Problem 3 2001.

Comment: In bullet 1, when I am considering the two-girl block, $(GG)G$ and $G(GG)$ are two different arrangements.  But, as you suggested, when I assign $G_1, G_2, G_3$ into those three spots, they are the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

You have $20$ different seat-combinations for the girls:

- $2,4,6$
- $2,4,7$
- $2,4,8$
- $2,4,9$
- $2,5,7$
- $2,5,8$
- $2,5,9$
- $2,6,8$
- $2,6,9$
- $2,7,9$
- $3,5,7$
- $3,5,8$
- $3,5,9$
- $3,6,8$
- $3,6,9$
- $3,7,9$
- $4,6,8$
- $4,6,9$
- $4,7,9$
- $5,7,9$

Then, you can permute the girls in $3!$ different ways.

Then, you can permute the boys in $7!$ different ways.

Hence the total number of ways to arrange them is $20\cdot3!\cdot7!$.