# A problematic way of thinking on arranging 7 boys and 3 girls in a row

Tags: combinatorics

The question is the same as the one asked here [7 boys and 3 girls](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1498329/in-how-many-ways-can-7-boys-and-3-girls-be-arranged-in-a-row-so-that-the-end-pos)
how many ways to arrange them in a row so that both ends are boys and no girls adjacent.
I clearly understand the two approaches to solve this permutation problem.
**First Approach**, arrange the 7 boys first (7!)
                next, there are 6 available slots for 3 girls, that's P(6,3)
    so total is 7! * P(6,3)
**Second Approach**, Arrange the 3 girls first (3!)
   next, first assume there is no difference between 7 boys
     1. arrange 4 boys into the 4 available slots ( 1 way to arrange)
     2. distribute the 3 rest boys arbitrarily into the  4 slots, that's
        (3+4-1,3)
     3. now consider the full permutation of the boys 7!
      so the answer is 3! * (6,3) * 7! = 7! * P(6,3), which agrees with the first answer

Now the trouble comes when I tried to think in the below way to achieve the same permutation and I failed to spot what went wrong .
  **Third (problematic) approach**
    1. first arrange the 3 girls, that's 3!
    2. then arrange 4 boys into the 4 slots, that's P(7,4)
    3. now there are 3 boys left
       the first one will have 8 available slots to be placed ( 8)
       the second one will have 9 available slots to be placed (9)
       the last one will have 10 available slots to be placed (10)
    so the answer is 3! * P(7,4) * 8 *9 * 10. 
    Obviously this doesn't agree with the answer and obviously it is wrong.

could you help me to spot the reasoning flaw(s) in the last approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you are overcounting the solutions with your final approach.  Suppose we have a couple of boys called Adam and Bob, and a couple of girls called Carol and Diana.

Now suppose we consider a permutation that looks something like: ... Carol Adam Bob Diana ... .

In your counting scheme, we would count this multiple times - first when Adam is chosen as one of the first four boys (going between Carol and Diana) and then Bob is chosen (to go between Adam and Diana), and second when Bob is chosen first (to go between Carol and Diana) and then Adam (to go between Carol and Bob).

The number of ways each permutation is overcounted depends on how the boys are distributed between the girls, so it is not a constant.  That makes it difficult to get to a clean expression using this approach.

Comment: My pleasure.  It's great that you're thinking about different ways of approaching these problems.  The technique of double-counting - enumerating the same set in two different ways to get an equation between two formulae - is a very elegant way of proving a lot of equalities in this field!

Comment: Regarding approach 3, it works in scenario "distribute r distinct objects into n distinct boxes, and the orderings of objects in each box counts", the total number of ways is n(n+1)(n+2)....(n+(r+1)). Applying the approach 2 to the same scenario yields the same result.
The confusion I still have is that why approach 3 works only in the above scenario ( without over counting) but not in the Boys and Girls problem. While Approach 2 can survive both scenarios.